# VBA class instances

Tags: vba, class, excel, object

I'm having an issue in VBA where every item in the array is being replaced every time i add something to that array.

I am attempting to go through the rows in a given range and cast every row of that into a custom class (named 'CustomRow' in below example). there is also a manager class (called 'CustomRow_Manager' below) which contains an array of rows and has a function to add new rows.

When the first row is added it works fine:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvTmx4NDN3cmtYeGs/view?usp=sharing

however when it loops around to the second row it replaces the contents of the first row as well as add a second entry:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvNXNLM3FCNUR0VHc/view?usp=sharing

Any ideas on how this can be solved?

*I've created a bit of code which shows the issue, watch the 'rowArray' variable in the 'CustomRow_Manager' class*

*Macro file*
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvUXYwNG5YdkoySHc/view?usp=sharing

*otherwise code is below:*

Data

```
    A   B   C
1   X1  X2  X3
2   xx11    xx12    xx13
3   xx21    xx22    xx23
4   xx31    xx32    xx33
```

Module "Module1"

```
Public Sub Start()
Dim cusRng As Range, row As Range
Set cusRng = Range("A1:C4")
Dim manager As New CustomRow_Manager
Dim index As Integer
index = 0
For Each row In cusRng.Rows
    Dim cusR As New CustomRow
    Call cusR.SetData(row, index)
    Call manager.AddRow(cusR)
    index = index + 1
Next row
End Sub
```

Class module "CustomRow"

```
Dim iOne As String
Dim itwo As String
Dim ithree As String
Dim irowNum As Integer


Public Property Get One() As String
    One = iOne
End Property
Public Property Let One(Value As String)
    iOne = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Two() As String
    Two = itwo
End Property
Public Property Let Two(Value As String)
    itwo = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Three() As String
    Three = ithree
End Property
Public Property Let Three(Value As String)
    ithree = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RowNum() As Integer
    RowNum = irowNum
End Property
Public Property Let RowNum(Value As Integer)
    irowNum = Value
End Property

Public Function SetData(row As Range, i As Integer)
    One = row.Cells(1, 1).Text
    Two = row.Cells(1, 2).Text
    Three = row.Cells(1, 3).Text
    RowNum = i
End Function
```

Class module "CustomRow_Manager"

```
    Dim rowArray(4) As New CustomRow
    Dim totalRow As Integer

    Public Function AddRow(r As CustomRow)
        Set rowArray(totalRow) = r

        If totalRow > 1 Then
            MsgBox rowArray(totalRow).One & rowArray(totalRow - 1).One
        End If
        totalRow = totalRow + 1
    End Function
```

Comment: Read e.g. [this article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) about ```auto-instancing variable```. In general, you should avoid auto-instancing variables. HTH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is using

```
Dim cusR As New CustomRow
```

inside the `For` loop.  This line is actually only executed once (note that when you single F8 step through the code it does not stop on that line)

Each itteration of the `For` loop uses the same instance of cusR.  Therefore all instances of `manager` added to the class point to the same `cusR`

Replace this

```
For Each row In cusRng.Rows
    Dim cusR As New CustomRow
```

with this

```
Dim cusR As CustomRow
For Each row In cusRng.Rows
    Set cusR = New CustomRow
```

This explicitly instantiates a new instance of the class

Comment: That did the trick! i hadn't even thought of that as i usually code in .NET where you would be able to explicitly create new instances within a loop.

Comment: I feel this particular behavior isn't well documented.  There is a difference between `Dim v As New ClassObject` And `Dim v As ClassObject Set v = New ClassObject`, however this is the only place I have found it documented.